# Resolve conversion warning when converting from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I was trying to port my MFC application from VS2008 to VS2010 and observed the below mentioned warning:
"VCWebServiceProxyGeneratorTool is no longer supported. The tool has been removed from your project settings."

We dont use web server proxies in our application. So this setting is not useful for my application. I want my code to be ported with 0 warnings. Is there any way or setting or configuration in which after porting my application from VS2008 to VS2010 I shall be able t remove this conversion warning.

Can anybody help as to what is it and how to resolve the same??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error converting project from VC++2008 to VC++2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124703/error-converting-project-from-vc2008-to-vc2010)

Comment: I checked the above link. it does not contain the resolution??

Comment: It is just a warning, the odds you actually need the tool in a MFC app ought to be close enough to zero.  Does it build?  If not and you actually need to generate web service proxies then upgrading the project is not a great idea.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It is just a warning. Also, as we dont generate web service proxies through my application. So, keeping the warning as it is would work.

Comment: Yes, that question is also unanswered. A duplicate question says nothing about whether it contains an answer to your question, it just says that the question is the same and the answers should be consolidated to one place.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I did not see that link initially.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way is to create a new project in `Visual Studio 2010` and import only the files you need from `Visual Studio 2008`.

Having said that, I have upgraded a few projects from `Visual Studio 2008` or older to `Visual Studio 2012` and encountered the warning multiple times, but have not seen it impacting the project itself.

Read up on [this comprehensive blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx) for Visual Studio project upgrading gotchas.

**TL;DR**: you can safely ignore this warning.